# MYSQL Event UPDATE of values

Tags: mysql

hello stackoverflow.

ive been looking around the web for a few hours now without success and i said,you know what - people usually dont want you to do this but ill just do it.

I'm trying to achieve an event in MYSQL that every hour checks if any of the columns containing a unix timestamp conatain a timestamp that is over 1 month / 3 months / 6 months old/older than the current time. and if it is change a value

Basically there are 3 columns

- `purchase_date` is the old timestamp
- `shop_type` is the column deciding if its 1/3/6 months being 1 ,2 or 3 accordingly
- `shop_status` is the column being set to "2" if that timestamp is older than the requirement above

id learn events right now but i seriously only need it 1 time and im sure other users might find this thread interesting

"mockup code"

```
Event every 1 hour

if (shop_type == "1" && (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP-purchase_date) >= 1month)
UPDATE shop_status == "2"

if (shop_type == "2" && (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP-purchase_date) >= 3months)
UPDATE shop_status == "2"

if (shop_type == "3" && (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP-purchase_date) >= 6months)
UPDATE shop_status == "2"
```

i know people hate people like me, but sometimes you have to just do it because noone else is going to help you. hope you understand..the event syntax is a bit weird

Comment: Just write a `SELECT` query that finds the rows you want, and run it via the event scheduler.

Comment: but i dont know how to find the right collums because of the current timestamp part.

Comment: You don't have to be so bitter when asking a question. Are you asking how to adapt that logic to MySQL? Something like `UPDATE tablename SET shop_status=2 WHERE shop_type=1 AND purchase_date>=?` where `?` is a date a month ago?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the following query from the event scheduler:

```
UPDATE shop_table
SET shop_status = "2"
WHERE (shop_type = "1" AND purchase_date <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
OR (shop_type = "2" AND purchase_date <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH))
OR (shop_type = "3" AND purchase_date <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH))
```